# Uploading files (video files) to S3 server from android using signed URL’s generated from server side application

Tags: android, file-upload, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I am trying to upload video files to a Bucket in S3 server from android app  using a signed URLs which is generated from server side (coded in python) application. We are making a PUT request to the signed URL but we are getting

> `connection reset by peer exception`.

But when I try the same URL on the POSTMAN REST CLIENT get a success message. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done this using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) HTTP client library,it successfully uploaded file to Amazon s3 server.

code:

```
 public interface UploadService {
    String BASE_URL = "https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/folder";

    /**
     * @param url :signed s3 url string after 'BASE_URL'.
     * @param file :file to upload,( usage: new TypedFile("mp4", videoFile);.
     * @param cb :callback.
     */
    @PUT("/{url}")
    void uploadFile(@Path(value = "url", encode=false) String url, @Body() TypedFile file, Callback<String> cb);
}
```

service class

```
public final class ServiceGenerator {

private ServiceGenerator() {
}

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, String baseUrl) {
    return createService(serviceClass, baseUrl, null, null);
}

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, String baseUrl, final String accessToken, final String tokenType) {

    class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
        @Override public Throwable handleError(RetrofitError cause) {
            return cause;
        }
    }

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
            .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateTypeAdapter())
            .disableHtmlEscaping()
            .create();

    RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(baseUrl)
            .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()))
            .setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler())
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson));

    if (accessToken != null) {
        builder.setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json;versions=1");
                request.addHeader("Authorization", tokenType +
                        " " + accessToken);
            }
        });
    }

    RestAdapter adapter = builder.build();

    return adapter.create(serviceClass);
}
```

and use:

```
    UploadService uploadService = ServiceGenerator.createService(UploadService.class,UploadService.BASE_URL);
uploadService.uploadFile(remUrl,typedFile,new CallbackInstance());
```

Comment: How can i feed the Cognito IDentity id and access token here

Comment: Hey @Aerrow, if you need cognito, maybe you don´t need to upload with signed urls. You can give permission to cognito user pool to have access to a bucket you define.

Comment: Hi @Shijil just looking into this topic today. I see your Retrofit call attaches some headers to the request. Those are for your own security model, right? Not an AWS thing, correct?

Comment: Image uploaded in this way is in corrupted state on S3. Is it working with anybody? I'm using Retrofit 1.8.

Comment: check this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55162161/put-upload-file-to-aws-s3-presigned-url-retrofit2-android/74140811#74140811

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic URL instead of providing the base URL, use @Url instead of @Path and pass a complete URI, encode= false is by default

Eg:

`@Multipart
@PUT
@Headers("x-amz-acl:public-read")
Call<Void> uploadFile(@Url String url, @Header("Content-Type") String contentType, @Part MultipartBody.Part part);`