# Access denied response from s3 during upload

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

viI am trying to upload file to a Amazon S3 server from android app using signed url which is generated from server side, its working fine on our testing Amazon s3 account but its return `'Access Denied'` error for live account with new bucket name.

```
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>my requestid</RequestId><HostId> my hostid </HostId></Error>
```

upload code:

```
public void UploadObject(String signed_url ) throws IOException
 { 
     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPut post = new HttpPut(signed_url);

     // uploading video file:
     post.setEntity(new FileEntity(getMyVideoFile(), "video/mp4")); 

     HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
     String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
 }
```

its working fine in ios for both account(signed url generated from same server side),Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You will probably need to post your Bucket Policy, signing code, and upload code. There is not a way to diagnose this based only on this error message.

Comment: The signature of a signed url is only valid for the bucket name originally used when creating the signature.  You aren't trying to use the *exact same* signature on two different buckets, right?

Comment: @ Michael we generate separate signed url for each bucket using same method(credentials, bucket name .. are different). please note signed urls works fine in ios.

Comment: Done using Retrofit lib, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32439404/2562861