# PUT upload file to AWS S3 presigned url Retrofit2 Android

Tags: android, amazon-s3, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a pre-signed upload URL from AWS S3 to upload a video file to. Testing on Postman the video is successfully uploaded. However i get a 403 returned when implementing in retrofit. I cannot use multipart upload for this task.

service call :

```
@Headers("Content-Type: video/mp4")
    @PUT
    fun uploadTaskAWS(@Url awsUrl: String, @Body filePart: RequestBody): Call<ResponseBody>
```

upload:

```
            val file = File(task.file_path)
            val requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/mp4"), file)
            val response = awsTaskUploadService.uploadTaskAWS(task.upload_url, requestFile)
```

I have ensured the URL is correct. The content type header is added too, postman screenshot attached. Getting 403 Forbidden Error

[screenshot of postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BSKK.png)

I have found this related question however i'm still getting a 403. [Upload a file to AWS S3 pre-signed URL using Retrofit2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991720/upload-a-file-to-aws-s3-pre-signed-url-using-retrofit2)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

solution was to include multipart and expect Single response not Call :

```
  @Multipart
    @PUT
    fun uploadAsset(
        @Header(CONTENT_TYPE) contentType: String,
        @Url uploadUrl: String,
        @Part file: MultipartBody.Part
    ): Single<ResponseBody>
```

where contentType is passed in

```
val requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(contentType), file)
val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(mediaType, task.file_name, requestFile)
assetService.uploadAsset(contentType, task.upload_url, body)
```

Comment: For others looking, I had the same problem and the suggested methods are now deprecated moreover Android now uses content providers making it tricky to access the underlying file, if interested I documented my solution [here](https://gutier.io/post/android-upload-file-to-aws-s3-bucket-with-retrofit2/)

Comment: Perfect solution. Follow link which @ZzAntáres has mentioned

Comment: Thank you @ZzAntáres.

Comment: Thanks boy @ZzAntáres . you saved my day.

Comment: Single is undefined. From where it should add

Answer (score 1):

403 error means the server knows who you are but do not have the authority to perform the desired action.

If the pre-signed URL is correctly generated, you should be able to upload without any authentication.

You can check if postman is by default adding any AWS Authentication to request

Also you need to explicitly set the protocol version while signing requests if uploading to a region that uses only version 4.

Comment: What do you mean by protocol version?

Answer (score -1):

***I tried many times with retrofit but no success, finally I can do it using HttpURLConnection***

```
 class UploadImageUsingPreSignedUrl(
    var bitmap: Bitmap?,
    var signedURL: String,
    var imageUploadCallback: ImageUploadCallback
) : AsyncTask<Void?, Void?, Int>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void?): Int {
        var respCode = -1
        try {
            val url = URL(signedURL)
            val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            connection.requestMethod = "PUT"
            connection.doOutput = true
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/png") // your content type
            val outputStream = connection.outputStream
            bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 70, outputStream)
            outputStream.close()
            respCode = connection.responseCode
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return respCode
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(responseCode: Int) {
        super.onPostExecute(responseCode)
        imageUploadCallback.imageUpload(responseCode == 200)
    }
}
```

Comment: where is ImageUploadCallback?

Comment: @aliozkara ,ImageUploadCallback callback having one method (imageUpload) that contain bool as an argument